# In .NET MAUI, is there an equivalent for the IsChecked and Checkable properties/bindings for MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, maui

In WPF, I would typically do something like this to implement a checkable menu item tied to a setting:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <DockPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            LastChildFill="True">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem FontSize="16" Header="_☰">
                    <MenuItem Header="_I Contain a submenu">
                        <MenuItem
                            Header="_I am checkable1"
                            IsCheckable="True"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},Path=IsSetting1Enabled}"
                            StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
                        <MenuItem
                            Header="_I am checkable2"
                            IsCheckable="True"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},Path=IsSetting2Enabled}"
                            StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
                    </MenuItem>
                    <!-- more menu content -->
                </MenuItem>                 
            </Menu>
<!-- more dockpanel content-->
</DockPanel>
<!-- more grid content-->
</Grid>
```

Can I do this in .NET MAUI? If so, how?

Settings.cs (since MAUI uses properties instead of settings):

```
    public static class Settings
    {
        public static bool IsSetting1Enabled
        {
            get => Preferences.Get(nameof(IsSetting1Enabled), false);
            set => SetPreference(IsSetting1Enabled, value, nameof(IsSetting1Enabled));
        }
        //More settings here
    }
```

My attempt at CheckableMenuFlytoutItem.cs:

```
    internal class CheckableMenuFlyoutItem : MenuFlyoutItem
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public bool IsCheckable { get; set; }
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public event EventHandler Checked;
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public event EventHandler Unchecked;
        protected virtual void OnChecked(EventArgs e);
        protected virtual void OnUnchecked(EventArgs e);
    }
```

MyContentPage.xaml:

```
                   <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Date Display (Input)">
                        <CheckableMenuFlyoutItem
                                Name="SimpleTimeInputCheckbox"
                                Text="Simple Time"
                                IsCheckable="True"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.IsSetting1Enabled}" />
```

But I don't know how to properly implement OnChecked and OnUnchecked, and while I'm trying to adapt the WPF source code at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/MenuItem.cs,d31d1ae141bfea57, I haven't had much luck yet.

Can anyone help me either by pointing to an existing implementation of a checkable menu item for MAUI, or by getting me started on building my own?

Comment: `WPF isn't open source, right?` - it is https://github.com/dotnet/wpf - though I didn't understand how this could help you with your issue in MAUI?!?

Comment: Thank you - it might help seeing how this particular feature is implemented in WPF so I can port it to MAUI. Currently trying a combination of WPF source code and pieces taken from https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/CheckBox/CheckBox.cs, will update if/when I make progress

Comment: well good luck with that, I don't know MAUI - so can't really help

Comment: Maui is based on the WinUI3, and it does not have the `IsCheckable` and `IsChecked` properties for MenuItem.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT And it doesn't look like WinUI is open source, right? So I couldn't use the RadioMenuFlyoutItem (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.radiomenuflyoutitem?view=winui-2.8) to try and implement my own version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear this is not currently available in MAUI, nor has anyone implemented a version of it that I have found. I have submitted a feature request on the MAUI GitHub repository:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16635